# Debug Rock, Paper Scissors game? Javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone help me debug this simple rock paper scissors game?

I believe the error has something to do with the playgame() function

```js
function playgame() {
  let userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toUpperCase();
  let computerChoice = computerPlay();
  console.log(rpsgame(computerPlay, userChoice));
}

function computerPlay() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3) + 1);
  if (computerPlay == 1) {
    computerPlay = "ROCK";
  } else if (computerPlay == 2) {
    computerPlay = "PAPER";
  } else {
    computerPlay = "SCISSORS";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`return` terminates the function immediately; your `computerPlay` function will never progress past the first line. Rather, you should put the `random` call into a *variable*, and then return either `ROCK`, `PAPER`, or `SCISSORS`. You also shouldn't try to reassign the function name (`computerPlay`) to a string.

```js
function playgame() {
  let userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toUpperCase();
  let computerChoice = computerPlay();
  console.log(computerChoice);
}

function computerPlay() {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3));
  if (rnd === 0) {
    return "ROCK";
  } else if (rnd === 1) {
    return "PAPER";
  } else {
    return "SCISSORS";
  }
}
playgame();
```

If you want *both* the random numeric index *and* the name of the choice in `playgame`, you might return the chosen random number immediately in `computerPlay` and then have `playgame` convert it to a name. Use object lookup rather than `if/else` for more brevity:

```js
function playgame() {
  const playNames = {
    0: 'ROCK',
    1: 'PAPER',
    2: 'SCISSORS'
  }
  let userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toUpperCase();
  let computerChoice = computerPlay();
  console.log(computerChoice + ' aka ' + playNames[computerChoice]);
}

function computerPlay() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}
playgame();
```

Answer (score 0):

In computerPlay function you return in 1st line where you do the randomization, which terminates the function. I suspect you want your function to return the string value no the integer. So you should replace the return with 'let choice' or smth. like that and in if sentences return the string value.